# Control Fly Mode With Joystick?

Tags: camera, customization

Is it possible to control the camera movements when in fly mode in Cycles with some external device, preferably joystick to get a smooth movement?

Instead of using keyboard keys <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>? Did anybody try that?

Comment: Maybe with https://joytokey.net or something similar ?

Comment: Hi,t hanks for the answer. Sorry, I didn't mention I'm on Mac. I think Joytokey is PC only.But anyway, did you try yourself? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I just started doing research on this subject. I would try a program like "Gopher360" you can do custom keyboard and mouse binds with a Xbox controller. It's not through Blender but it should get the job done in theory.

Comment: Did you test it? This community is about **practical** solutions.

Comment: Hi, is it PC only? because im on mac. Anyway, will have a look at it, thanks for the suggestion.